# Getting unknown text in footer of email

Tags: plugins, themes, email

I am getting some extra text in some wordpress email. I don't know from where its set.

Here is an example

> abctest, 3, rue Passet 3, rue Passet, Lyon, N/A, N/A, Malta
>   [image]
>   I check for "woocommerce_email_footer_text" hook, but its not from there.

It's append before `**</body>**`. I also test for disable all plugin and check one by to check may be some plugin used "wp_footer" hook.

Please help me to fix this issue, I will be very thankful.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Since this email is generated by WooCommerce and not WP Core, you may find more assistance on a Woo-specific site. This site mostly stays away from helping with plugins.

Comment: This email is not by WooCommerce, It's generated from WP Mail SMTP test email

Comment: Ok - please see this site's Help Center https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help for more about what is considered on-topic. :) In your situation I'd highly recommend disabling all plugins and testing an email, if possible - or disable all plugins except WP Mail SMTP so that you can send that same test email without any other plugins in the mix. You can determine from that test whether or not another plugin is affecting it. If not, try switching to a default theme and rerun the test, to check whether it's the theme.

Comment: I got the solution. It was set from server - Cloudways. Thanks @WebElaine